# Remove duplicate code in the reducer in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have duplicate code in reducers. Where only the name of the property changes. How can I refactor to remove duplicates?

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM: {
        if (state.toggleCost) {
            let last = state.costs.length
            return {
                ...state,
                costs: [...state.costs, { name: action.propertyName, value: action.value, id: last + 1 }
                ],
            }
        } else {
            let last2 = state.profit.length
            return {
                ...state,
                profit: [...state.profit, { name: action.propertyName, value: action.value, id: last2 + 1 }]
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
case ADD_ITEM: {
    let key = 'profit'
    if(state.toggleCost){
        key = 'costs'
    }
    return {
        ...state,
        [key]: [...state[key], { name: action.propertyName, value: action.value, id: state[key].length + 1 }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure of what `propertyName` actually holds, usage of **ternary expressions** and **`[]` property accessor** can help us in refactor like so :-

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM: {  
    let fieldToUpdate = state.toggleCost ? 'costs' : 'profit';
    return {...state,[fieldToUpdate]:[...state[fieldToUpdate],{name: action.propertyName, value: action.value, id: state[fieldToUpdate].length + 1}]}
      
    }
```